# Symfony2 Application Parses YML On Every Request

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

My Symfony2 application has some performance problems, so I ran a webgrind on it in order to see what was happening. Turns out it was parsing huge amounts of YML files on every request and I can't figure out why. I already have APC caching enabled so I don't know what it could be. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Edit: Here is a screenshot of the webgrind I ran.
[image: http://i.imgur.com/m7g6l.jpg]

Comment: Delete the YML files, so they can't be loaded (or which kind of advice do you expect w/o actually giving no concrete information?).

Comment: What concrete information can I give? All the information the webgrind gave me was that the YML parsing functions were being called on every request, I don't know exactly which files are being parsed.

Comment: Are you running in production mode or development?  In production mode the results of YML parsing are cached.

Comment: Yes I was in prod mode when I ran that webgrind. I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 2):

From my research, it appears that the APCClassLoader does not cause Symfony2 to cache the YAML files used in Doctrine.  It appears to cache the configuration files by default (config.yml, parameters.yml), but the actual ORM YAML files used by Doctrine are not cached unless you specify a cache driver as shown in the documentation linked below:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers

So, it's possible that the solution above solved the issue if the poster had only configuration YAML and not doctrine YAML.  However, if Doctrine YAML is involved, a Doctrine cache driver must be specified.

This also affects people using Annotations as they will be parsed on each page load unless a cache driver is specified (other than the Doctrine default array cache).

Thought I should post because this is a complex issue and the answer above was misleading in my case where Doctrine ORM YAML files were the source of the caching issue.

This post has more details on my specific issue and the resolution:

[Why is Symfony2 app spending 70-90% of its time parsing YAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742766/why-is-symfony2-app-spending-70-90-of-its-time-parsing-yaml/25028082#25028082)

Comment: Hey, @Nate Stone, do you know if this doctring cache works with form validation *yaml* files as well?

Comment: The docs seem to indicate that validation uses APC by default according to this reference:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator/resources.html#caching
There is a related bug/feature thread where they discuss setting your own service:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/12975

Answer (score 1):

Figured out what was going on. I had APC enabled and working, but wasn't using the ApcUniversalClassLoader in my autoload.php. More details [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/performance.html). When they say in the docs "suggestions" for improved performance they really mean "you have to do this or your performance will be terrible."

Comment: I am very surprised that enabling APC had that effect. As @Cerad mentioned YAML files should be cached in production method, regardless of your class loader caching. I've run Symfony 2 without any class loader cache with great performance (using PHP opcache without apcu for instance).

Comment: Ryan - are you running 2.5+?  I'm running 2.3 and after stepping through the code, I found that Doctrine uses the default "array cache" which expires with each page load/instance.  

In 2.3, Doctrine metadata (ie. the YAML orm files) are parsed every page load unless you change this caching method to APC, memcached, or other options.  Perhaps 2.5 changes this behaivor.

In any case, I doubt the APC changes mentioned above had any effect on YAML either.  From what I see (and from the documentation), Doctrine will not use APC unless you specifically configure it to.

Comment: From looking at the documentation, 2.5 also requires Doctrine cache driver configuration so perhaps you already had this configured.  I'm curious if yours is running with the default settings for the ORM portion in app/config/config.yml or if it is, in fact, configured to use a proper cache.