# Why is Symfony2 app spending 70-90% of its time parsing YAML?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

As shown in the Webgrind output below, my app is spending most of its processing time on YAML parsing.

[image: Webgrind Output - 83.63 percent YAML parsing.]

Note: the Webgrind output is in "percent".  So, adding up the "Total Self Cost" shows 83.63 percent of the total time is spent processing YAML.

I've seen this related thread:

[Symfony2 Application Parses YML On Every Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871939/symfony2-application-parses-yml-on-every-request)

However, my implementation is using the ApcClassLoader class as seen below:

```
$loader = new ApcClassLoader('odr_dev', $loader);
$loader->register(true);
```

Additionally, I've checked the APC system using apc.php and my classes and pages are found in the APC cache and are being hit.  This takes place on either PROD or DEV on any request even after the caches are populated.

My theory is that we have a circular entity reference and the system can't successfully parse the YAML in order to cache it.  So, it ends up trying to parse the YAML on every request.

However, I don't see any errors about being unable to parse YAML or anything in the logs and am unsure how to determine if this could be the case or where to look next.

Comment: Have you traced back the specific invokers of the Parser->parse() function?

Comment: I've been working on that and expect to find what's invoking them tonight.  I'll post updates when I find out what is going on.

Comment: Note - I'm running 2.3.18 - the latest long term support version.  Perhaps this performs differently on different versions.  I posted my solution below (the accepted answer) and it pretty definitively works for this version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After stepping through every line of code involved in this process, I found that Doctrine is using the default "array" cache which is only valid for a single page load.

I think myself and many others assumed that when we turned on APC it would also be used by Doctrine for metadata caching.  In fact, Doctrine defaults to its array cache unless otherwise specified.

This page lists the Doctrine configuration options:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

After adding cache driver options to my `/app/config/config.yml` as shown below:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
        result_cache_driver:
            type: memcached
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 11211
            instance_class: Memcached
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: memcached
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 11211
            instance_class: Memcached
        query_cache_driver:
            type: memcached
            host: 127.0.0.1
            port: 11211
            instance_class: Memcached
```

After the fix, the same page shows *no* YAML parser interaction and loads in 302ms vs. 5851ms for a total speedup of 19X.  Additionally, the cachegrind file went from 121MB to 3.4MB and these results are generally consistent over a number of trials.

Here is the same Webgrind showing the difference:

[image: Webgrind Fixed]

So, basically, it was a configuration issue.  From what I've seen in StackOverflow questions and other forums, it seems there is a disconnect here about how caching works.  Essentially, you need to explicitly turn it on for Doctrine caching as outlined above or it uses a basically useless default.

Symfony2 can sometimes be too "configurable" and this is one instance where it never occurred to me that it would be separately configurable.  In that regard, it's a powerful feature (being able to use separate caches for things), but until you figure this out, the system is totally compromised as far as speed is concerned.

Comment: Note: I chose to use Memcached for my metadata caching as the new PHP opcode cache deprecates APC and APC is not available on newer PHP installations.  Essentially, this future-proofs the solution for a while as long as Memcached is supported by PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the issue. We only use cross-request caching in production (and not always there). Using the Doctrine array shouldn't kill your performance. I think the caching you've turned on may just be hiding a larger issue with your YAML. Unless you have a huge number of Doctrine metadata files?

Comment: All my doctrine files show as 100% ok according to symfony's dev interface.  Additionally, it is clear that this is a required setting from looking at the code.  If you're running without it, I'm nearly 100% certain you'll be running faster if you cache this stuff.

Comment: Thank you. I decreased loading time from 1.4 sec to 0.3

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is probably recursive YAML resources (or similar). You are seeing 4000+ invocations of `Yaml\Parser::parse`. In a test of my own app (which is fairly complex) on a page load with a completely empty cache I only see 166 invocations. And that drops to 2 invocations for page loads with a warm cache.

I don't think your use of a class loader cache would have any impact on YAML parsing, as you discovered. I suspect the ticket you link to is probably wrong)

Comment: Thanks for the info on how many parser invocations your code sees.  I agree that mine seems too high and tends to indicate a circular reference or something. I figured this must be something solely with caching or that the parser was somehow bailing out before completing.  In fact, the parser does complete and the metadata is successfully stored.  So, the solution is ... (see my answer)